# How to trigger play in spotify android app

Tags: android, android-intent, spotify

In the latest version spotify remembers the last played song. Now I want to automatically resume playback after a certain event.

I tried using tasker.

I start the app, then tried to send

- KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY

and

- KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE

But both don't work.

KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY ==> opens google music
KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE ==> opens Samsung MP3-Player

Both apps can't be uninstalled.

Additionally I tried to change the default music player with "Default App Manager".
No change...

**So I am searching for a way to trigger the "play" in spotify for android directly.**

Smartphone: Samsung Galaxy S3, Android 4.1.1
Spotify Android: 0.6.0.17

Answer (score 3):

How are you sending the intent for `KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY`, and are you calling the `setComponent` method?  I had the same issue, but then found I need to specify the media button receiver (Spotify) via `setComponent` when creating the `ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON` intent.

You can get the receiver by calling `getMediaReceivers` (of PackageManager) and passing in a  `ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON` intent object.  This will provide a list of all packages that register to receive media button events.  Next, go through the list, find which one is Spotify (or your player of choice) via ResolveInfo and activityinfo.name, then pass `activityinfo.packageName` and `activityinfo.name` into a new `ComponentName` object.

Finally, pass the `ComponentName` object into the `setComponent()` method of your `ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON` intent.